# PHP Form Validation Code

Tags: php, html, forms

I have checked all this code carefully but still it doesnt work not sure why. The error is when i fill all options it still shows "Please fill all the fields"

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password_again']) && !empty($_POST['gender']) && !empty($_POST['info']) ){
     $username = $_POST['username'];

}   
else{
    echo "You need to fill all fields";
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
<body>
<form method= "post">
<h2>Register</h2>
username:<input type ="text" name ="usename"/><br/>
password:<input type ="password" name ="password"/><br/>
password again:<input type ="password" name ="password_again"/><br/>
Gender: male<input type ="radio" value="male" name ="gender"/> female<input       type ="radio" value="female" name ="gender"/><br/>
Tell us about yourself:<br/>
<textarea name="info">
</textarea>
<br/>
<input type ="submit" value = "submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change `<input type ="text" name ="usename"/>` in `<input type ="text" name ="username"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the field and the name in your php file aren't the same. You are checking for the field **username** while your name is **usename**.

Change this line

```
<input type ="text" name ="usename"/>
```

To this

```
<input type ="text" name ="username"/>
```

It should now work.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mark my answer by clicking on the checkmark, if your question is answered? Thanks!